# Whats wrong with my index?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table, here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_data_cache` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `enterTollgateNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exitTollgateNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carType` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `distanceBetweenTollgate` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hour0` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour1` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour2` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour3` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour4` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour5` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour6` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour7` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour8` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour9` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour10` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour11` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour12` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour13` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour14` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour15` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour16` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour17` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour18` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour19` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour20` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour21` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour22` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `hour23` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `countHourer` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `DateIndex` (`date`) USING HASH,
  KEY `QrySearchStandard` (`date`,`enterTollgateNumber`,`exitTollgateNumber`,`carType`),
  KEY `DateIndexBetween` (`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7797493 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE `total_each_day` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `normalCarTotal` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bigCarTotal` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`),
  KEY `Index 2` (`date`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

3rd table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ramp_block` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `classification` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `placeName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rampBlockName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tollgateCode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tollgateName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tollgateName2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In 1st table I have created 3 indexes but they seem not to be used. Here is my query:

```
select 
    (c.normalCar + c.bigCar) as correctionNow,
    (t.normalCarTotal + t.bigCarTotal) as totalNow,
    (c2.normalCar + c2.bigCar) as correctionYesterday,
    (t2.normalCarTotal + t2.bigCarTotal) as totalYesterday,     
    DATE(td.DATE) AS realDate,
 from table_data_cache  as td
    left outer join total_each_day as t on date(t.date) = date(td.date)
    left outer join total_each_day as t2 on date(t2.date) = date_sub(date(td.date) , interval 1 day)
    left outer join correction as c on date(c.date) = date(td.date)
    left outer join correction as c2 on date(c2.date) = date_sub(date(td.date) , interval 1 day)

     where  td.enterTollgateNumber in (3,4,7,13,19,23)
       and  td.exitTollgateNumber in (2,5,9,15,17,21,25,29,33,37,40,41) 
       and date(td.date) >= date('2009-01-01')
       and date(td.date) <= date('2009-01-02') 
       and carType = 1
```

but index seems not appear

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | td    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6570156 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |     357 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |     357 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |      30 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |      30 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

What's wrong with my index here? I can't resolve it until now.

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but in for instance SQL Server when you apply a function to a column in the `WHERE` clause (such as your `date()` function) it negates the use of indexes because it forces a table scan.

Comment: @JNK is 100% right. The `date(t.date) = date(td.date)` is redundant and it will only slow down the query. Use `t.date = td.date` instead. Since both columns are `DATE` datatype, the query will be equivalent.

Comment: yeah that works

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/l5pwy6flb/image.png

Comment: Change the `where` as well. The `and date(td.date) >= date('2009-01-01') and date(td.date) <= date('2009-01-02')` could be written as: `and td.date >= date('2009-01-01') and td.date <= date('2009-01-02')`

Comment: And now the explain will show some more improvement. And I suggest you take all the last part (after "Answered by @JNK") and make it a real answer. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: ok this is done

Answer (score 1):

after @JNK and @ypercube giving me an advice

i found the solution

the problem is in date() function take a look useless date function in my query

```
select 
    (c.normalCar + c.bigCar) as correctionNow,
    (t.normalCarTotal + t.bigCarTotal) as totalNow,
    (c2.normalCar + c2.bigCar) as correctionYesterday,
    (t2.normalCarTotal + t2.bigCarTotal) as totalYesterday,     
    DATE(td.DATE) AS realDate,
 from table_data_cache  as td
    left outer join total_each_day as t on date(t.date) = date(td.date)
    left outer join total_each_day as t2 on date(t2.date) = date_sub(date(td.date) , interval 1 day)
    left outer join correction as c on date(c.date) = date(td.date)
    left outer join correction as c2 on date(c2.date) = date_sub(date(td.date) , interval 1 day)

     where  td.enterTollgateNumber in (3,4,7,13,19,23)
       and  td.exitTollgateNumber in (2,5,9,15,17,21,25,29,33,37,40,41) 
       and date(td.date) >= date('2009-01-01')
       and date(td.date) <= date('2009-01-02') 
       and carType = 1
```

and i will remove all date() function

so the final works query should be like this

```
select 
    (c.normalCar + c.bigCar) as correctionNow,
    (t.normalCarTotal + t.bigCarTotal) as totalNow,
    (c2.normalCar + c2.bigCar) as correctionYesterday,
    (t2.normalCarTotal + t2.bigCarTotal) as totalYesterday,     
    td.DATE AS realDate,
 from table_data_cache  as td



    left outer join total_each_day as t on t.date = td.date
    left outer join total_each_day as t2 on t2.date = date_sub(td.date , interval 1 day)
    left outer join correction as c on c.date = td.date
    left outer join correction as c2 on c2.date = date_sub(td.date , interval 1 day)
     where  td.enterTollgateNumber in (3,4,7,13,19,23) 
       and  td.exitTollgateNumber in (2,5,9,15,17,21,25,29,33,37,40,41)   
       and td.date >= date('2009-01-01') 
       and td.date <= date('2009-01-02') 
       and carType = 1
```

here are  the result

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                | key       | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | td    | range  | DateIndex,QrySearchStandard,DateIndexBetween | DateIndex | 4       | NULL            |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY   | 3       | traffic.td.date |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY   | 3       | func            |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY   | 8       | traffic.td.date |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY   | 8       | func            |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
```

thanks again @ypercube and @JNK